# SQL- ORDER BY DESC is not fetching results correctly

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-order-by

I'm trying to fetch the maximum value of the column but the SQL query doesn't respond exactly.

This is my complete query

```
select batch_upload_id from 
 (select batch_upload_id from cor_branch_upload 
  order by BATCH_UPLOAD_ID desc) 
where rownum = 1
```

It should return 10 but it returns 9
[image]

Comment: To get maximum just use `select max(cast(batch_upload_id as number)) as max_batch_upload_id
from cor_branch_upload` but consider changing data type of the id column as well

Comment: Please do **not** post code as images. See here for more details why: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551

Comment: It's a string, so the order is correct.

Answer (score 3):

Try

```sql
select batch_upload_id from 
(select batch_upload_id 
 from cor_branch_upload 
 order by TO_NUMBER(BATCH_UPLOAD_ID) desc) 
where rownum = 1
```